# подскажите как правильно работать forEach JS?

Tags: javascript, foreach

```
    btnPlus = document.getElementsByTagName('button'),
        incomePlus = btnPlus[0],
        expensesPlus = btnPlus[1];
     btnPlus.forEach(function (item) {
                item.expensesItems.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
                item.expensesPlus.setAttribute('disabled', 'true');
            });
```

> правильно ли пищу код?

Answer (score 0):

Смотрите какой тип данных возвращает метод. `getElementsByTagName` возвращает экземпляр типа `HTMLCollection`. У экземпляров данного типа нет метода `forEach`.

Чтобы использовать данный метод, нужно `HTMLCollection` сначала преобразовать в массив. Другими словами в экземпляр типа `Array`, у которого данный метод имеется. Например так:

```
let array = Array.from(btnPlus);
array.forEach(.......
```

Другие методы возвращают другие типы, например метод `document.querySelectorAll` возвращает экземпляр типа `NodeList`, у которого есть метод `forEach`.

В вашем примере

```
btnPlus.forEach(function (item) {
    item.expensesItems.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
    item.expensesPlus.setAttribute('disabled', 'true');
});
```

если бы он был рабочим, в аргументе `item` был бы элемент кнопки, у которого нет свойств `expensesItems` и `expensesPlus`, если вы их где-то раньше не задали этой кнопке.